# Detecting unchanged values using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbcontext, objectcontext

Is there a way, I can resolve below situation?

I have a Department entity as below and it has populated the data.

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Location { get; set; }
```

I am making a change in Name and Location properties.
Assume below are the values for the properties:

```
Name="HR";
Location="Location1";
```

While data flows in my application, these two values get changed to something other than the original values.

```
Name="IT";
Location="Location2";
```

Now, again I am setting the properties values to whatever it was earlier.

```
Name="HR";
Location="Location1";
```

Upon calling context.SaveChanges(), EF triggers the update query updating the same field. Though, it doesn't make any difference.

Is there a way, I can prevent that ? Other than putting manual check for property change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little method to cancel false changes:

```
void MarkRealChanges(DbEntityEntry entry)
{
    foreach (var name in entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
    {
        entry.Property(name).IsModified =
            !entry.OriginalValues[name].Equals(entry.CurrentValues[name]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MarkRealChanges(context.Entry(department));
```

A context stores original values of each entity it has loaded. While the context is used, on many occcasions the change tracker executes `DetectChanges`, which stores the *current* values of entities and marks properties as changed when there are differences. Apparently, reverting this mark has never been on EF's agenda, so you have to do it manually.

Comment: That seems to be feasible option but I am looking for some alternative to do that. The reason behind is, my object deals with almost >50 properties and I have huge collection of objects bound to context, this fix indeed solves the purpose but it has overhead of looping through each property.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no alternative. The change tracker is misinformed (if you like), so that's the place to fix it. Or you should change your strategy altogether and shorten the context's lifespan.

Comment: Of course you could apply this method in an override of SaveChanges and loop through modified entities only.